# SUM if value or another value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a simple measure that sums the total of a column if multiple conditions are true. This is the table:

[image]

I want to sum the value in the 'value' column if it is type 'A' or type 'B'.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a measure like this:

```
total= CALCULATE(SUM(table[Value]), table[Type] IN {"A","B"})
```

If you want it to react to a filter on type you can change it to:

```
total= CALCULATE(SUM(table[Value]), KEEPFILTERS(table[Type] IN {"A","B"}))
```